# assert_difference('Course.count') expects difference but there is no change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I'm running a test to try to add a course to my database, but for some reason it doesn't seem to be adding since when I run:

```
test "should create course" do
    assert_difference('Course.count') do
      post :create, course: { name: 'New',
                              course_code: '1' }
    end

    assert_redirected_to course_path(assigns(:course))
  end
```

I get:

```
"Course.count" didn't change by 1.
<3> expected but was
<2>.
```

What's weird is that when I run the rails console and do

```
@course = Course.new(name: 'New', course_code: '1')
@course.save
```

the course saves correctly in the database.

Here is the code for the create action:

```
def create

    @course = Course.new(params[:course])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @course.save
        @registration = Registration.new
        @registration.active = true
        @registration.user = current_user
        @registration.course = @course
        @registration.course_code = @course.course_code
        @registration.instructor = true
        @registration.save!
        admin = User.find_by_email('admin@email.com')
        @registration = Registration.new
        @registration.active = true
        @registration.user = admin
        @registration.course = @course
        @registration.course_code = @course.course_code
        @registration.instructor = true
        @registration.save!

        format.html { redirect_to @course }
        format.json { render json: @course, status: :created, location: @course }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @course.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is the relevant model code for the Course model:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :create_unique_identifier
  attr_accessible :name, :course_code

  # Relationships
  has_many :registrations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :assignments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :registrations

  def create_unique_identifier
    begin
      self.course_code = SecureRandom.hex(4)
    end while self.class.exists?(:course_code => course_code)
  end
```

Does anyone know why I might be getting this error?

Comment: Well, but these are not the same things! We don't see what's happening in your course controller. But whatever it is, it doesn't lead to your Course getting saved.

Comment: If there are already two courses in your database, is it possible you already stored one with `course_id: 1` and the second one fails because of a uniqueness constraint?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev don't both of them just try to store a new course in the database? I'll add the controller code for the create action as well though

Comment: @Drenmi the course id is optional actually since it's just going to be randomly generated I think when you save it, so can take it out of the test, but it still doesn't pass the test

Comment: Also, in your controller test it's `course_code`, but in console it's `course_id`. (your snippets)

Comment: And finally, post the relevant model code (validations, before_ hooks, etc.)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev woops the course_id part was a typo and I added the model code